# DDD: Distribute Interfacing and Reporting logic over Bounded Contexts of Core Domains or use a designated Bounded Context (Generic Domain)?

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, domain-driven-design, reporting, bounded-contexts

We are developing an architecture (from scratch) based on Domain Driven Design (DDD), having roughly three Bounded Contexts each corresponding to one Core Domain. There is also a Bounded Context (Generic Subdomain) for monitoring our applications, as well as a Bounded Context (Generic Subdomain) for performing scheduled jobs (coming from the Core Domains but are treated as black-boxes by the scheduler).

There are two more requirements for which we are unsure how to model them:

- **Reporting** (that is, pixel-precise reports)
- **Interfacing** with external systems that are not part of our domain (e.g. preparing a bunch of XML files ready to be picked-up through a web service (WSDL) during the night by the government; or exposing part of the model of one core domain as a simplified SQL database ready to be queried by third parties)

We can think of two approaches each:

1. *Integrate Reporting and Interfacing into the Bounded Context they belong to*, thereby potentially duplicating infrastructure code.

   - In case of Reporting, we would check-in the report definition files (e.g. Microsoft's RDL) into the Git repositories of the individual Bounded Contexts and deploy them to a centralised reporting server.
   - In case of Interfacing, we would develop the aforementioned XML-generation logic and web service as projects in the Git repository of that Bounded Context, and deploy it as part of that Bounded Context too.
2. *Create designated Bounded Contexts* for Reporting and Interfacing each, thereby unifying the technologies but distributing aspects of the core domains.

   - In case of Reporting, we would manage all report definition files belonging to different core domains in a designated Git repository, together with all the code necessary to create and show the reports.
   - In case of Interfacing, we would manage all 'ports and adapters' in a single Git repository for all core domains, potentially using a very heterogeneous set of interface technologies like REST or WSDL or OpenAPI or SQL. This Bounded Context would then consume the Published Languages (in our case this is all Web API using Open API standard) of the Bounded Contexts it should interface with, and provide itself the interface for the outside world.

I think the discussion boils down to two independent dimensions: Technology and business. Should we keep everything business-related together, or should we cluster around technology/infrastructure (i.e. everything interface-related and everything reporting-related)?

Comment: How did you proceed ?

Comment: We opted for the second solution, i.e. group by reporting/interfacing and handle those aspects in a centralized way. However, all source of business information is still inside the respective bounded contexts, and both reporting and interfacing just do technical transformations/aggregations on that data.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, option 1 would duplicate infrastructure code, that sounds like a smell in your code.

Option 2 would distribute aspect of the core domain, but that is fine because bounded contexts can communicate with each other.

Also, in your case, Reporting and Interfacing with external systems are each a bounded context of it's own, so it should be a separate layer/context in your application.